# Setting initcwnd and initrwnd for persistent start on network-manager restart

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager

I need to have the following routes initiate persistently whenever network-manager service is restarted (both manually, and upon resume from suspend/hibernate).

`ip route change default via 10.0.0.1 dev wlo1 proto static metric 600 initcwnd 10 initrwnd 10`

`ip route change 10.0.0.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.5 metric 600 initcwnd 10 initrwnd 10`

`ip route change 169.254.0.0/16 dev wlo1 scope link metric 1000 initcwnd 10 initrwnd 10`

I already have this going into affect at system start/reboot which is working fine from /etc/rc.d/rc.local.

However I discovered when network-manager restarts after system suspend/hibernate the ip route settings are no longer present for initcwnd 10 and initrwnd 10. At this point in time I just manually run my /etc/rc.d/rc.local script to apply the settings again.

Hope someone can provide a more automated way to have this done in situations I've mentioned above.

Even more helpful, could the initcwnd/initrwnd values be permanently compiled into the kernel?

Answer (score 0):

For making any script/command to be run with NetworkManager, you can create a script under `NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` and include the required command. This would be read and executed every time NetworkManager is restarted or if the host is rebooted with NetworkManager service enabled. For example you could create a file call `10-initcwnd` under the directory and have a script like:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "wlo1" ] && [ "$2" = "up" ]; then
    ip route change 169.254.0.0/16 dev wlo1 scope link metric 1000 initcwnd 10 initrwnd 10
fi
```

The Ubuntu manpage about `dispatcher.d` can be found [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/NetworkManager.8.html#contenttoc3) for reference.